# Custom footer on the first page with Title

Tags: header-footer, titles, footer

I'm returning to LaTeX after a few years of not using it so excuse the silly question.

I am using an image in my header so have used the following to clear the default contents of the `fancyhdr` package, include the image and create a footer:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\
\usepackage{lastpage}\
\fancyhf{}\
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}\
\setlength\headheight{26pt} \
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Header}}
```

It all works fine except that the first page, which includes the title, still has the default footer style. I can make that disappear but I want this page to have the same footer as the other pages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First page of the document is by default `plain`

So use this code in your preamble (without replacing yours)

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
   \fancyhf{}%
   \fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}%
   \setlength\headheight{26pt}% 
   \rhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Header}}%
}
```